# Json object merge with unqiue id

Tags: json, node.js

I have multiple json Objects

```
json1 = [
    {'category_id':1,'name':'test1' },
    {'category_id':1,'name':'test2' },
    {'category_id':1,'name':'test3' },
    {'category_id':2,'name':'test2' },
    {'category_id':3,'name':'test1' }
];

json2 = [{'category_id':1,'type':'test1'}];

json3 = [
    {'category_id':1,'color':'black'},
    {'category_id':2,'color':'black'},
    {'category_id':3,'color':'white'}
];
```

I am expecting output like this

```
final = [
    {'category_id':1,'name':'test1','type':'test`','color':'black' },
    {'category_id':1,'name':'test2','type':'test`','color':'black' },
    {'category_id':1,'name':'test3','type':'test`','color':'black' },
    {'category_id':2,'name':'test2','color':'black' },
    {'category_id':3,'name':'test1','color':'white' }
];
```

As i have long json object. Looping is good idea or not ? Does there is any inbuilt function for doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) you can achieve it via:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/axLoyfx7/)

```
var jsons = [json1, json2, json3];

var final = {};

// merge all data
_.each(jsons, function (jsonArr) {
    _.each(jsonArr, function (json) {
        final[json.category_id] = _.extend({}, final[json.category_id], json);
    });
});

// map it back onto json1    
var finalArr = _.map(json1, function (json) {
    return final[json.category_id];
});
console.log(finalArr);
```

Final value of finalArr:

[image]

Comment: where it retunrs ? how shoul i check output

Comment: Added a [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/axLoyfx7/). + You should include [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) in your code. Or if you use `jQuery` you can use that as well.

Comment: pls read my question. As in demo only unique category is showing

Comment: Is [this structure (see image)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rDDFg.png) not what you wanted?

Comment: Oh sorry. now I see that you wanted the categories duplicated. Is that really the expected result? If yes I will delete my answer

Comment: No, All object of json1 must be there. just want to other json into first having same category_id

Comment: Updated answer/[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/axLoyfx7/) to match desired output

Comment: can we do it without using _(underscore)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do the same in plain javascript. :)

```
var final = {};

var jsons = [json1, json2, json3];

for(var i=0;i<jsons.length;i++){
    final[i]=jsons[i];
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iMaverick/urpo5u5u/)

EDIT:

Well, you will have to do it programmatically!

Comment: Pls check my question and required output carefully